# ohlc data has differing length columns - cannot perform arithmetic with other dataframes?

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm trying to calculate Premium Stochastic in R using Quantmod and TTR but I keep getting the following error:

```
 >tmp=EMA(EMA(((marketdata$Close-LL)/(HH-LL)*100-50)*0.1,5),5)
Error in EMA(((marketdata$Close - LL)/(HH - LL) * 100 - 50) * 0.1, 5) : 
  Invalid 'n'
```

marketdata is a dataframe containing OHLC data.  It works fine when using a csv file but when importing yahoo finance data into the dataframe it seems to have differing column lengths. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the source code of `EMA` and it says:

```
    if (n < 1 || n > NROW(x)) 
    stop("Invalid 'n'")
```

In your case, `n` is defined as `5`. This means that `n < 1` is `FALSE`. Therefore, `n > nrow(x)`.

But... that's odd. You are supplying a vector, and `nrow` of a vector is `NULL`. Turns out, if you read `?EMA`, `x` has to be a matrix.

The lesson from all this is that you should always carefully read the help page of a function if something goes wrong, especially with packages. If you can't find the answer there, try to look into the source code by typing the function name; often this is enough to find which line throws the error.

Also, try `rollmean` from `zoo`, that one works pretty well:

```
library(zoo) 
a <- 1:10
rollmean(a,5)
# 3 4 5 6 7 8
```